# php automatic daily http login request

Tags: php, xml, http, authentication

I need to recover XML data from a news provider for a website. In order to do so, I need to send a url request to authenticate on a daily basis, and then I need to include the authentication ID with every new request I send. Basically the session expires every 24 hrs and then I need to request a new one to keep receiving my (non-RSS) news feeds. Is there any way to automate this process? With cURL maybe? My knowledge of PHP is fairly basic but I don't imagine I need to manually go into the file every morning, request the ID and copy the numerical string into all of my data requests...?  Also I don't know if this is common practice or if it is specific to our news provider, but any help, or if someone could maybe point me to a PHP tutorial on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Jane

Comment: depending on the system you use, Scheduler for windows, and cron for linux

Comment: Ibu -- thanks! It's actually for a Drupal site... so cron I guess...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can createe your php file to tdo the job then use either:

[Windows SCheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742545.aspx) to perform the job at a specific time

or

[Cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) to do the same thing in a unix based system,

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: OK, so then the authentication ID gets sent back to me as the attribute of an XML tag, which I have to include in every URL request I send back... can I somehow save the attribute as a variable, or do I have to input it manually in all of my requests? Many thanks!

Comment: since you are using an automated script it would make sense to have it save the return data in a database, which gets updated daily, and the requests that you send back will have to get the id from the DB on each request. maybe you should look in the api documentation for a better aproach but i am sure this one will work too

Comment: Wow... OK thanks... think I'm a little out of my depth here, but will look into it.